# Practical way to work with columns in responsive design - twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap v3.2 and was just wondering , what is the best way to make a site responsive while working with col-xs / col-sm ..etc

I'm setting these classes from css and trying to make the div container accommodate its contents in different screen sizes.

What I'm currently doing is, assign col-xs to a div while starting the browser at smallest width, and start resizing the browser window wider and choose other types (sm,md,lg) column width based on the browser width I'm currently viewing in (which I also estimate what the class of the current browser width should be). This is really tedious, specially when you are designing a complex structure.

I'm using Chrome browser.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you narrow it down to a specific use-case / scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I tend to do is sketch out my pages as wire-frames for the various different screen sizes I would like them to be viewed on. This way you have a clear overview of how things should be laid out when the viewport changes.

You should be strategically assigning multiple classes to each column so you can define how it looks for each of the breakpoints (480px (xs), 768px (sm), 992px (md), 1200px(lg)):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-9">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, the first column is 2/12 width between 480px and 992px, and for screens larger than 992px it is 3/12 width.

You can also just use a larger screen size column class and when the screen is smaller than specified it will just stack:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In that example, if the screen is bigger than 992px then the columns will be 3/12 and 9/12 respectively, but if the viewport is any smaller than they will stack on top of each other vertically.

You can also play around with the flow of the document using the push and pull classes. Say for example you have two columns that need to be side by side, but on mobile the one on the right needs to be on top. Going by the ordinary flow of things, the second column you define will end up on the bottom so you can do the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9" id="first">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3" id="second">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's happened there is the 3/12 column has been pushed by 9, and the 9/12 column has been pulled by 3, so they have swapped positions. What this means is that when they are side by side, they will be in reverse order but when the screen size is less than 992px (col-md), then first div will be on top and the second will be on the bottom, back to the regular flow.

To illustrate:

```
browser (> md)
+------------------------------------+------------+
| #second                            | #first     |
| col-md-9                           | col-md-3   |
| col-md-pull-3                      | ...-push-9 |
+------------------------------------+------------+

mobile (< md)
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 |
| col-md-3 col-md-push-9 #first                   |
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 |
| col-md-9 col-md-pull-3 #second                  |
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I hope this makes sense and that I interpreted your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`.col-xs` and `.col-sm` are good ways to make a site responsive.

On smartphones and small devices, don't forget to use `.hidden-xs` and `.hidden-sm` classes. Some information is not useful on small devices.

I wrote my page on `lg-desktop`. When it's done, I open 3 windows (`xs`, `sm`, and `md`) on my second screen. I reload them and modify my code, until all views are fine.

Sorry for my language, I'm not fluent in English.

Here is an example of responsive phpbb style: http://bootstrap.at-it.fr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correctly understood your question.
You choose the right class from javasript manually ?

Because if you do so, you don't have to choose beetween the xol-xs, col-md, col-lg... classes...
You just have to set all of them, the CSS media queries will choose the right class depending of the screen width.

ex :

```
<div class="main-content col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
```

Comment: I'm setting it from CSS and trying to make the current div accommodate the content of the div on different screen sizes.

Comment: <div class="main-content col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"> render the same views as <div class="main-content col-xs-9">

Comment: @AlexandreT sure, on a xs screen size... But I doubt he needs only the smallest config...

Comment: @Miam84, not true. If you only declare an xs column, it applies to all device columns (sm, md, lg). example: http://www.bootply.com/L404qMbBUf

Comment: OK I see what is the problem... it's about a bad example... I should have put different values for each sizes. The goal was to show the different media queries rules not to render the same style with every sizes... My bad.